# Comparing two car objects

Tags: java

I am just beginning to learn Java and am trying to compare two previously defined car objects within a class. None of my code is returning and error, but when car1 is the same as car2, my last line of code is NOT returning "Two vehicles are the same." Does anyone know why? Below, I added the entire car class as per the request below. Any help is really appreciated. I don't seem to understand how to implement the override equals to this code.

Comment: You need to implement the `equals(...)` method for your Car class. That is what properties of the Car class make the car equal? Search the site/web for more information about implement "equals".

Comment: As @camickr said you have to override the equals method from the Object class, then modify it there so it can be known when 2 objects of the same class equal each other.

Comment: Post your Car class here so then we can help you.

Comment: @Dren I added my car class above. Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: @ryan3282002   *I don't seem to understand how to implement the override equals*   - what did you search for? How many links did you read. What confuses you? Posting the class doesn't help, because we don't have all the information needed to solve the problem.. Learn how to problem solve on your own. You now know what the problem is. So it is easy to do your own search. How about keywords like "how do i implement equals method in java". Give somebody a fish and they eat for a day. Teach somebody to fish and they eat for life. I just taught you how to fish so you can problem solve on your own.

Answer (score 5):

You need to override the `equals` method; otherwise, it is only checking if the references are the same.

```
import java.util.Objects;
//...
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Vehicle v = (Vehicle) o;
    return Objects.equals(make, v.make) && Objects.equals(model, v.model) && year == v.year;
}
```

**Note:** For consistency, you should always override [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) along with overriding [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(make, model, year);
}
```

Comment: (1+) Like the Objects.hash(...) method. I've not see that before. Sure simplifies things.

Comment: @camickr  I hadn't either.  But it comes from `Arrays.hashCode` which exists for all the primitive arrays and a generic object array.

Answer (score 2):

With overriding the equals method from the Object class, we can specify when 2 objects of the same class equal each other.
Here in this code 2 objects are the same if their make , model and year are the same.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(obj instanceof Vehicle){
        Vehicle v = (Vehicle)obj;
        return  v.getMake().equals(this.make)
                && v.getModel().equals(this.model)
                && v.getYear() == this.year;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Override the `hashCode` method too

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(make, model, year);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Dren. I upvoted your response but it did not reflect in StackExchange. Thanks again!

Comment: @ryan3282002 You don't have enough reputation for that

Comment: @ryan3282002 it doesn't matter, keep learning

Comment: @Dren If you don't like the edit just roolback

Comment: @dreamcrash Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I always use CompareToBuilder from Apache and you can choose what fields to use . You can find how to use it here -> https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/CompareToBuilder.html

Code will look like next:

```
  public class MyClass {
   String field1;
   int field2;
   boolean field3;

   ...

   public int compareTo(Object o) {
     MyClass myClass = (MyClass) o;
     return new CompareToBuilder()
       .appendSuper(super.compareTo(o)
       .append(this.field1, myClass.field1)
       .append(this.field2, myClass.field2)
       .append(this.field3, myClass.field3)
       .toComparison();
   }
 }
```